# How to get id of Jquery knob

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-knob

I am using `jquery knob`,I want to get the `id` of the knob on  change function.

```js
$(".dial").knob({
  'min': 0,
  'max': 5,
  'readOnly': false,
  'width': 70,
  'height': 70,
  'dynamicDraw': true,
  change: function(value) {
    console.log("changed to: " + value);
  },
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="dial" value="2" id="test" disabled="disabled">
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `this.$.attr('id');` in the `change`  function

Check out the working **[FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/WhCLk/34/)**

Comment: This is a great answer ... I'm wondering if you can explain "how" or "why" this works.  I don't understand the syntax "this.$"?

Comment: @Kolban : I am not sure..I actually went through their docs and got it by trial and error, I have neva used jquery knob myself